# Error with download after 60 seconds in Shiny Server

Tags: r, linux, apache, shiny

I've got a Shiny app hosted on a linux machine in a docker container. There is a long calculation in a download function and it times out at exactly 60 seconds and returns a "Failed - Server problem" as the download and a 502 error appears in the apache logs. If the calculation takes less than 60 seconds, then everything works.

The app also works without error when hosted on shinyapps.io, so the problem seems to be something with my configuration of shiny server or the [apache proxy settings](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy).

I thought adding `http_keepalive_timeout 600;` to the top of /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf would help. It didn't.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `connectiontimeout` and `timeout` values in the server redirect

`ProxyPass /FOLDER-WITH-APP/ http://localhost:9999/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300`

(in addition to http_keepalive_timeout 600; in the shiny server config file)